# How to handle datetimeoffset(7) datatype in snowflake?

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl, sqldatatypes, timezone-offset

I have a DDL that has LastUpdatedTime with datatype datetimeoffset(7) in sql server. what's the equivalent datatype in snowflake or how to handle this to get exact value that is in source.

I tried using LastUpdatedTime TimeStamp_TZ(9)

SQLServer Source: 2023-05-16 18:33:20.8659596 +00:00
Snowflake: 2023-05-16 18:33:20.865 +0000

SQL Server
Tstamp: 0x000000008EF278B5

How to retain same value as in SQL server in snowflake

Instead of using FORMAT(CAST(LASTUPDATEDTIME AS DATETIME), N'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), How to retain same date value with offset or retain datetime format(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Comment: can you pls add some sample data? have y ou tried `TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) )` ?

Comment: Source SQL SERVER: 2023-05-16 18:33:20.8659596 +00:00
Snowflake :2023-05-16 18:33:20.865 +0000

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is the `TIMESTAMP_TZ` type.

From [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime):

> `TIMESTAMP_TZ` internally stores UTC time together with an associated *time zone offset*. When a time zone is not provided, the session time zone offset is used. All operations are performed with the time zone offset specific to each record.

This aligns with the same concept in `datetimeoffset` from SQL Server, in that the offset is stored with the date and time in a single field.

It also goes on to say:

> `TIMESTAMP_TZ` values are compared based on their times in UTC.

That is also the case for `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server.

The main difference between the two is that SQL Server does not have a concept of a "session time zone", but that only matters in Snowflake's `TIMESTAMP_TZ` type if you don't supply an offset.

Indeed, from the example you gave, you are starting with a `DATETIME` type, which has no time zone.  Thus it is the session time zone that is controlling the offset when you cast.

You can read about how to set the Snowflake session time zone [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#label-timezone), and in [this blog post](https://www.propeldata.com/blog/managing-timezone-settings-in-snowflake).